# Why chant digvimokaḥ (releasing the protection) after the completion of mantra japa?

Tags: mantras

Traditionally before japa, two nyāsas, karanyāsa and aṅganyāsa are performed and aṅganyāsa ends with digbandhaḥ (invoking protection all around).

In some cases once the japa is over, digvimokaḥ (releasing the protection) is done.

What is the reason for chanting digvimokaḥ (releasing the protection)?

Comment: The circle of protection that you have drawn around yourself with Digbandhana will stay permanently if you do not remove it by Digvimogaha

Comment: @Rickross I thought that is a good thing!  Why would you remove protection?  The whole purpose of the multitude of raksha stotrams and kavachams are to get this protection right?  I wonder if there is a particular reason this sort of protection is removed after the chant is over.

Comment: The Digbandanah protection is meant to be there only while doing the Japa .. the protection that one gets by reciting Kavacham is meant to be present all throughout the day

Comment: @Rickross Yes. I think you are right.  It makes sense that the digbandana protection is meant to be there only for the duration of the japa but still I do not understand the need to chant the dikvimoka.  It is done only in some cases, I think like when doing sandyavandanam.  For Rudram dikvimoka is not chanted for instance.

Comment: I think its better to follow the instructions for a particular Japa as it is .. when Digvimigaha is not mentioned then of course we do not need to do it but I don't understand why it is not needed in certain cases.

Comment: @Rickross Yes. That is my doubt as well.  I agree with you it is always better to follow the instructions given by the seers/acharyas.